# How to remove only letters from a string in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I'm working with BigQuery SQL right now trying to figure out how to remove letters but keep numeric numbers. For example:

```
XXXX123456
AAAA123456789
XYZR12345678
ABCD1234567
1111
2222
```

All have the same amount of letters in front of the numbers along with regular numbers no letters. I want the end result to look like:

```
123456
123456789
12345678
1234567
1111
2222
```

I tried using PATINDEX but BigQuery doesn't support the function. I've also tried using LEFT but that function will get rid of any value and I don't want to get rid of any numeric value only letter values. Any help would be much appreciated!

-Maykid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '[^0-9]', '')
```

Answer (score 5):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'XXXX123456' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AAAA123456789' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XYZR12345678' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABCD1234567' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1111' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2222' 
)
SELECT str, REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'[a-zA-Z]', '') str_adjusted
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```